# Почему не нажимается кнопка после объявления её VISIBLE

Tags: java, android

У меня имеется обработчик нажатия кнопок и кнопка которую я скрывают еще в xml, вне `onCreate` у меня имеется класс с методом в котором я объявляю:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавь еще флаги

```
setFocusable(true);
setClickable(true);
```